# marker color in plotly

Tags: python, plotly

Have a code:

```
fig = go.Figure()
x_for_plot = np.array([1,2,3,4])
y_for_plot = np.array([1,2,3,4])
colors=np.array([0.1, 0.2, 0.5, 0.7])
fig.add_trace(go.Scatter(
  x=x_for_plot,
  y=y_for_plot,
  name="TEST",
  marker=dict(
    size=15,
    cmax=1,
    cmin=0,
    color=colors,
    colorscale="Rainbow_r",
    symbol='circle',
    line=dict(color=colors, width=3)
  ),
  showlegend=True,
  hoverinfo='text',
  hovertext="text",
  hoverlabel=dict(bgcolor="white", font_color="black"),
  mode='markers'))
fig.show()
```

Why are marker colors and line colors different? How to make it the same?
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jDHqw.png)

read documentation.

Comment: Do you want the line color to be the same (like black for all) OR do you want it as different colors (if so, what) OR the color to be the same as the marker color?

Comment: Wouldn't it be the same if we disabled `cmax`,`cmin` and set the same color scale for the lines?

Comment: Same as the marker color.

Comment: Then just comment out this part - `line=dict(color=colors, width=3)`. It will show the scatter dots with one color... is that you what you are looking for?

Comment: No. The task is to make a ring. color='white', line=dict(color=colors, width=3). But due to the fact that the color is different, the logic is violated

Comment: cmax,cmin are required for the task

Comment: I am more confused now :-) You want the marker to be white inside and the colors of rainbow_r outside?

Comment: Yes. But my colors inside and outside are different, so I asked this question

Comment: Change `color=colors,` to `color="#FFFFFF",` ... that will change the color inside to white. Leave the line as you have in your code above.

Comment: You can do this, but the logic will be broken. The color must be the same inside and outside. Added a screenshot to the question